# Standardized regression coefficients, need to extract one from the table

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract 1/4 standardized regression coefficients using lm.beta, and hitting a snag.  Usually I would just code `model$coefficients[x]`, but I have always been pulling unstandardized coefficients before.  For some reason, it does not appear to work on the standardized version.  I am getting all kinds of weird results.  Is there another way to do this?  Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I am confused as to why this would be a problem. Below is the code chunk.  It's just a standardized regression table, and I need one value.

`top_dog=lm.beta(new_lreg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fitting Regression And Getting Betas

You didn't provide data (I advise doing that next time) but I have used the `iris` dataset native to R to show you how it can be done. First fit a regression:

```
#### Run Iris Regression ####
iris.lm <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length,
              data = iris)
```

Then save the betas as an object:

```
#### Save Betas as Object ####
beta.iris <- lm.beta::lm.beta(iris.lm)
```

#### Printing Beta Coefficients

You can call the coefficients this way:

```
#### Call Them ####
beta.iris$standardized.coefficients
```

Which will give you this printout:

```
 (Intercept)  Sepal.Width Sepal.Length 
          NA   -0.3305168    0.8328950
```

If you want a specific coefficient you do so like this:

```
#### Select Which ####
beta.iris$standardized.coefficients[2]
```

Which will give you the Sepal.Width beta:

```
Sepal.Width 
 -0.3305168
```